# Why is a Tkinter frame not showing all three buttons unless gui is dragged into wider/bigger size

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, fill, expand

I have a gui which is not showing the buttons the way I would like. The frame is being cropped unless the gui is stretched.[image]

Like this, where finally I see the three buttons desired:
[image]

I want to have the frame with the buttons (frame2) always show the three buttons and maintain the same size irregardless of the size the gui is enlarged to. Any idea of where I am going wrong?

***Code***

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter                  
from tkinter import ttk 
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#=====================================================================
# ROOT FIGURE FOR GUI
#=====================================================================
root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry("600x450") 
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
 
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Circle Cal') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='OPW')

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

#MAKE A FIGURE OBJECT
my_figure1 = Figure(figsize = (4, 4), dpi = 100) 

#MAKE A FRAME WIDGET
frame1 = tk.Frame(tab1, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#create another frame(frame2) 
frame2 = tk.Frame(tab1, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.E, fill=tk.BOTH)

#MAKE A CANVAS OBJECT
my_canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(my_figure1, master = frame1) # creating the Tkinter canvas containing the Matplotlib figure  

# TURN THE CANVAS OBJECT INTO A CANVAS WIDGET
my_canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tkinter.TOP, fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1) # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
my_canvas1.draw()

def plotData():
    pass
def clearPlot():
    pass

# MAKE BUTTON TO PLOT GRAPH
button1 = tk.Button(frame2, text = "Plot", command = plotData, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
# MAKE BUTTON TO CLEAR PLOT
button2 = tk.Button(frame2, text = "Clear", command = clearPlot, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
# MAKE BUTTON TO close
button2 = tk.Button(frame2, text = "Close", command = clearPlot, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], there's too much extraneous stuff in the code.

Comment: Please remove all of the unused import statements, and any other code not directly related to the question being asked. Also, it doesn't appear that it's possible for this code to run. You import tkinter "as tk", but later try to use `tkinter.TOP`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I will remove all the irrelevant imports. The code as it stands runs on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply that there isn't enough room for the buttons. You're forcing the size of the window to be a specific width and the width is just too small.

When you force a window to be a specific size, `pack` will need to shrink one or more widgets to make all of the widgets fit. It does this in the reverse order that the widgets were added with `pack`.

Since you want the canvas to be the widget that grows and shrinks, you need to pack the frame that contains it last. So, call `pack` on `frame2` before calling `pack` on `frame1`.

This is easiest if you group your calls to `pack` together rather than interlacing them with widget creation.

```
frame2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.E, fill=tk.BOTH)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing

```
root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget")
#root.geometry("600x450")
```

the geometry manager

Answer (score 0):

Try it in full screen:

```
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
```